# how to reconnect to IBM MQ without timer

Tags: ibm-mq

I wrote some codes to get message from remote mq but after message is not available into Queue I disconnect from MQ . Then I want to reconnect to MQ . I added timer for this . But it increases open input count . Is there any way to reconnect without timer? any clue will do fine .

**CODE**
C# code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using IBM.WMQ;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Timers;

namespace MQMessageSender
    {
    public class MQTest
    {
        private static MQQueueManager queueManager;
        private static MQMessage queueMessage;
        private static MQGetMessageOptions queueGetMessageOptions;
        private static MQQueue queue;
        static string strReturn = "";
        static string QueueName;
        static string QueueManagerName;
        static string ChannelInfo;
        static string channelName;
        static string PortNumber;
        static string transportType;
        static string connectionName;
        static bool running = true;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            getMessage();
        }

        public static void connectMQ()
        {         
            QueueManagerName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QueueManager"];
            QueueName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Queuename"];
            ChannelInfo = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ChannelInformation"];
            PortNumber = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"];
            char[] separator = { '/' };
            string[] ChannelParams;
            ChannelParams = ChannelInfo.Split(separator);
            channelName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Channel"];
            transportType = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TransportType"];
            connectionName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionName"];
            queueManager = new MQQueueManager(QueueManagerName,
            channelName, connectionName);
            strReturn = "Connected Successfully";

            // return strReturn;
        }

        public static  void getMessage()
            {
            connectMQ();
            queue = queueManager.AccessQueue(QueueName,
            MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);

            while (running)
            {
                try
                {
                    queueMessage = new MQMessage();
                    queueMessage.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
                    queueGetMessageOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions();
                    queue.Get(queueMessage, queueGetMessageOptions);
                    strReturn = queueMessage.ReadString     (queueMessage.MessageLength);
                    //messageavailable = MQC.MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE;
                    // strReturn1 = strReturn + "@@@@@@@" + messageavailable;
                }
                catch (MQException exp)
                {
                    strReturn = "Exception: " + exp.Message;
                }


                if (strReturn != "Exception: MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE")
                {
                    string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xmlFilePath"];
                    string fileName = path + "MQMessage" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + ".xml";
                    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, strReturn);
                }
                else if (strReturn == "Exception: MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE")
                {
                    queueManager.Disconnect();
                    string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["logFilePath"];
                    string fileName = path + "MQLog" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + ".txt";
                    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, strReturn);
                    System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
                    aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
                    aTimer.Interval = 30000;
                    aTimer.Enabled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    queueManager.Disconnect();
                    string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["logFilePath"];
                    string fileName = path + "MQLog" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + ".txt";
                    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, strReturn);
                    System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
                    aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
                    aTimer.Interval = 30000;
                    aTimer.Enabled = true;
                }
            }
        }

        public static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

So here I used timer to reconnect but it increases open input count . Please help

Comment: I would suggest you add a get with wait and just loop "while true".

Answer (score 2):

> So here I used timer to reconnect but it increases open input count

That's because you are not closing the queue before opening it again.

```
queueManager = new MQQueueManager(QueueManagerName, channelName, connectionName);
```

Using MQQueueManager class this way means that there is no security i.e. SSL/TLS or security exit.  Bad idea.  You should set the connection information in a Hashtable and pass the Hashtable to the MQQueueManager class.

Also, you should be using "MQGet with wait" rather than polling using a timer.

Here is a sample C# program that uses a Hashtable for connection information and performs an "MQGet with wait":

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using IBM.WMQ;

/// <summary> Program Name
/// MQTest62
///
/// Description
/// This C# class will connect to a remote queue manager
/// and get messages from a queue using a managed .NET environment.
///
/// Sample Command Line Parameters
/// -h 127.0.0.1 -p 1415 -c TEST.CHL -m MQWT1 -q TEST.Q1 -u tester -x mypwd
/// </summary>
/// <author>  Roger Lacroix
/// </author>
namespace MQTest62
{
   public class MQTest62
   {
      private Hashtable inParms = null;
      private Hashtable qMgrProp = null;
      private System.String qManager;
      private System.String inputQName;

      /*
      * The constructor
      */
      public MQTest62()
          : base()
      {
      }

      /// <summary> Make sure the required parameters are present.</summary>
      /// <returns> true/false
      /// </returns>
      private bool allParamsPresent()
      {
         bool b = inParms.ContainsKey("-h") && inParms.ContainsKey("-p") &&
                  inParms.ContainsKey("-c") && inParms.ContainsKey("-m") &&
                  inParms.ContainsKey("-q");
         if (b)
         {
            try
            {
               System.Int32.Parse((System.String)inParms["-p"]);
            }
            catch (System.FormatException e)
            {
               b = false;
            }
         }

         return b;
      }

      /// <summary> Extract the command-line parameters and initialize the MQ variables.</summary>
      /// <param name="args">
      /// </param>
      /// <throws>  IllegalArgumentException </throws>
      private void init(System.String[] args)
      {
         inParms = System.Collections.Hashtable.Synchronized(new System.Collections.Hashtable(14));
         if (args.Length > 0 && (args.Length % 2) == 0)
         {
            for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i += 2)
            {
               inParms[args[i]] = args[i + 1];
            }
         }
         else
         {
            throw new System.ArgumentException();
         }

         if (allParamsPresent())
         {
            qManager = ((System.String)inParms["-m"]);
            inputQName = ((System.String)inParms["-q"]);

            qMgrProp = new Hashtable();
            qMgrProp.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);

            qMgrProp.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, ((System.String)inParms["-h"]));
            qMgrProp.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, ((System.String)inParms["-c"]));

            try
            {
               qMgrProp.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, System.Int32.Parse((System.String)inParms["-p"]));
            }
            catch (System.FormatException e)
            {
               qMgrProp.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, 1414);
            }

            if (inParms.ContainsKey("-u"))
               qMgrProp.Add(MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, ((System.String)inParms["-u"]));

            if (inParms.ContainsKey("-x"))
               qMgrProp.Add(MQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, ((System.String)inParms["-x"]));

            System.Console.Out.WriteLine("MQTest62:");
            Console.WriteLine("  QMgrName ='{0}'", qManager);
            Console.WriteLine("  Output QName ='{0}'", inputQName);

            System.Console.Out.WriteLine("QMgr Property values:");
            foreach (DictionaryEntry de in qMgrProp)
            {
               Console.WriteLine("  {0} = '{1}'", de.Key, de.Value);
            }
         }
         else
         {
            throw new System.ArgumentException();
         }
      }

      /// <summary> Connect, open queue, read (browse) a message, close queue and disconnect. </summary>
      ///
      private void testReceive()
      {
         MQQueueManager qMgr = null;
         MQQueue inQ = null;
         int openOptions = MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;

         try
         {
            qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qManager, qMgrProp);
            System.Console.Out.WriteLine("MQTest62 successfully connected to " + qManager);

            inQ = qMgr.AccessQueue(inputQName, openOptions);
            System.Console.Out.WriteLine("MQTest62 successfully opened " + inputQName);

            testLoop(inQ);

         }
         catch (MQException mqex)
         {
            System.Console.Out.WriteLine("MQTest62 cc=" + mqex.CompletionCode + " : rc=" + mqex.ReasonCode);
         }
         catch (System.IO.IOException ioex)
         {
            System.Console.Out.WriteLine("MQTest62 ioex=" + ioex);
         }
         finally
         {
            try
            {
               if (inQ != null)
                  inQ.Close();
               System.Console.Out.WriteLine("MQTest62 closed: " + inputQName);
            }
            catch (MQException mqex)
            {
               System.Console.Out.WriteLine("MQTest62 cc=" + mqex.CompletionCode + " : rc=" + mqex.ReasonCode);
            }

            try
            {
               if (qMgr != null)
                  qMgr.Disconnect();
               System.Console.Out.WriteLine("MQTest62 disconnected from " + qManager);
            }
            catch (MQException mqex)
            {
               System.Console.Out.WriteLine("MQTest62 cc=" + mqex.CompletionCode + " : rc=" + mqex.ReasonCode);
            }
         }
      }

      private void testLoop(MQQueue inQ)
      {
         bool flag = true;
         MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();
         gmo.Options |= MQC.MQGMO_WAIT | MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
         gmo.WaitInterval = 2500;  // 2.5 seconds wait time or use MQC.MQEI_UNLIMITED to wait forever
         MQMessage msg = null;

         while (flag)
         {
            try
            {
               msg = new MQMessage();
               inQ.Get(msg, gmo);
               System.Console.Out.WriteLine("Message Data: " + msg.ReadString(msg.MessageLength));
            }
            catch (MQException mqex)
            {
               System.Console.Out.WriteLine("MQTest62 CC=" + mqex.CompletionCode + " : RC=" + mqex.ReasonCode);
               if (mqex.Reason == MQC.MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE)
               {
                  // no meesage - life is good - loop again
               }
               else
               {
                  flag = false;  // severe error - time to exit
               }
            }
            catch (System.IO.IOException ioex)
            {
               System.Console.Out.WriteLine("MQTest62 ioex=" + ioex);
            }
         }
      }

      /// <summary> main line</summary>
      /// <param name="args">
      /// </param>
      //        [STAThread]
      public static void Main(System.String[] args)
      {
         MQTest62 write = new MQTest62();

         try
         {
            write.init(args);
            write.testReceive();
         }
         catch (System.ArgumentException e)
         {
            System.Console.Out.WriteLine("Usage: MQTest62 -h host -p port -c channel -m QueueManagerName -q QueueName [-u userID] [-x passwd]");
            System.Environment.Exit(1);
         }
         catch (MQException e)
         {
            System.Console.Out.WriteLine(e);
            System.Environment.Exit(1);
         }

         System.Environment.Exit(0);
      }
   }
}
```